# WPF Square Cells

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I try to create a WPF custom control which combines a `TextBox` with two buttons. For the layout I use a grid with the `TextBox` in the first column and the buttons in the last two columns.

Now, I want to make the last two columns square - but I have no idea how to get there. My XAML looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Demo.Wpf.Controls.ConfirmationButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo.Wpf.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="28.341" d:DesignWidth="226.904">

    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True" x:Name="layoutGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=myRow, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=myRow, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="myRow" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"></Rectangle>

        </Grid>
    </Border>

</UserControl>
```

But the grid looks still like this:

[image]

So what I am doing wrong here? Any idea?

Comment: Have you run built/run the code? When i copy your code it is (in the designer) displayed like your image. But when i run the code once, it is displayed as shown in the answers below. Is there something else which could interfere with your layout?

Comment: ever found your solution for this problem and want to share it so others can find the answer?

Answer (score 2):

For transparence, I don't recommend setting layout sizes on the control level as Ian recommends. This will make it harder to adapt it in the long run.
So here is my solution binding the width of the `ColumnDefinition` to the `ActualHeight` of the Grid. Also, I don't recommend using names for binding-purposes if you can avoid it. A control with a name will stay loaded the entire time even if it is not visible or out of scope!

```
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid ShowGridLines="True" x:Name="layoutGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"></Rectangle>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well I got it working by binding to height of a rectangle itself, just take a look:

```
<Rectangle Name="rect1" Fill="Green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="{Binding ElementName=rect1, Path=ActualHeight}"></Rectangle>
<Rectangle Name="rect2" Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Width="{Binding ElementName=rect2, Path=ActualHeight}"></Rectangle>
```

[image]

Comment: @gadasadox Consider upvoting answer if you find it useful (especially for OP to see valuable answer :) ).

Comment: I don't recommend setting sizes on control level you will look for hours later when you want to change it where you declared it

Comment: @DenisSchaf That's personal preference and how you organize your project :)